# How to insert a new row into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert values into a mysql database using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SearchTerm, SearchResult) 
VALUES (?, ?), ("TestTerm", "TestResult");
```

I get the error message that there is an error "near '?, ?) ("TestTerm", "TestResult")' at line 1".

Would someone mind pointing out my mistake?

Comment: This is trivial question; look into the docs

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2):

The `?` is used with frameworks like PDO and mysqli. A normal insert looks like this

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SearchTerm, SearchResult)
VALUES ('TestTerm', 'TestResult');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SearchTerm, SearchResult)
SELECT 'TestTerm', 'TestResult';
```

Answer (score 1):

Script direct:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SearchTerm, SearchResult) 
VALUES ("TestTerm", "TestResult");
```

With [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SearchTerm, SearchResult) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a [perpared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). The idea is that the question marks stand in for values that may contain query-breaking character (namely semi-colons and quotes).

If you're using a library, you usually need to use two steps to do this. E.g., in java:

```
PreparedStatement ps = new PreparedStatement( "INSERT INTO TestTable (SearchTerm, SearchResult) VALUES (?, ?)");
ps.execute("TestTerm", "TestResult");
ps.execute("Escaped;Term", "TestResult");   // the semicolon will be escaped for you
```

Most every language has generic SQL libraries that allow you to do this. What language are you using?